# Inverse function of round; solving equations involving round function

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, rounding-error

I am trying to solve the equation with which I came up from the accounting task:

```
Round((0.844+delta)*1; 2)=0.89
```

or generally:

```
Round((a+delta)*n; 2)=b; delta=?
```

Of course, delta is not single value, it is interval, set of values but to achieve uniqueness let define the final solution delta^ as:

```
delta^=sgn(delta)*Min(Abs(delta))
```

Of course, I can always run iterative search with the step value 0.001 to solve the problem, but maybe there exist explicit function of delta^ as a function of a, b, and n?

It is the usual arithmeitc rounding with 2 positions.

Comment: $\operatorname{round}(x,d)=y \iff \operatorname{round}(10^dx)=10^dy \iff 10^dx\in[10^dy-0.5,10^dy+0.5]$. Can you take it from here?